# JWT token. Error "AADSTS700027: Client assertion contains an invalid signature"

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, postman, jwt

I need to get OAuth2 Access Token from Azure Active Directory. For this, I am using certificate based method. I have uploaded .crt file to Azure AD and got the certificate thumbprint from the Azure AD UI.

Now I am generating JWT token from JWT.io and trying it using postman. But I always get the following error:
"AADSTS700027: Client assertion contains an invalid signature. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client"

I am not sure what could be causing this. In JWT.io I am entering Base64 encoded thumbprint of public certificate (which I uploaded on Azure AD) as x5t parameter. This thumbprint I got from Azure portal UI as mentioned above.

In JWT.io I am entering public (crt) and private (key) certificates under "Verify Signature" and can see that the signature has matched.

Please let me know if anyone has any idea about this.

Comment: Could you show the code you are trying to use?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this error is usually caused by the fact that you did not encode the thumbprint correctly. After you obtain the thumbprint, please check your code to ensure that it is properly Base64 encoded.

Check the format of your JWT token at https://jwt.io/, you can refer to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/987660/oauth-oidc-client-auth-using-a-signed-jwt-instead-of-a-secret) and [certificate credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials):

Header

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "x5t": "<Base64 Thumbprint>"
}
```

Payload

```
{
  "iss": "<clientid>",
  "sub": "<clientid>",
  "exp": 1570838377 (expiration time),
  "jti": "<random unique identifier>",
  "aud": "https://<token-endpoint>"
}
```

Drop your private key  in to the bottom verify-er which will sign your JWT in the "Encoded" window.

I found some cases for your reference, I hope it can help you:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/320069/authentication-to-dynamics-365-using-azure-apps
and
https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad/issues/453

Comment: Yes. The problem was that I did not use Base 64 encoded X5t value. I was using hex encoded value and it looks like Graph API does not like it.

Comment: @user13260866  Yes, try to convert it to base64 encoding in the code.

Comment: You can generate a base64 encoded x5t value by running the following powershell commands: `$Certificate = Get-Item Cert:\CurrentUser\My\<self signed and uploaded cert thumbprint>` and then `[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Certificate.GetCertHash())` if you have your cert stored in your local cert store.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share with you that I get this exact same error if I request an access token using a new certificate, right after I just added the new certificate to my AAD app via MS Graph (/addKey).  If I immediately try again without changing anything, it is successful.  It doesn't seem to matter how long I wait before the 1st try, it's like it needs to fail once before the new cert is ready for use.  If I upload certs in the GUI, the issue never surfaces.

I know it's not the same issue you're having, but it's worth knowing what else AAD will give this exact error message for.

Comment: Oh ok. Yes, not the same scenario. The issue you are seeing could be because of timezone settings. I saw something similar in my testing and it was solved after syncing time.